# Orthographe du participe présent de ressourcer

Tags: orthographe, phonétique

Je viens de croiser le mot "ressourçant" avec un "ç" alors que le verbe ressourcer s'écrit avec un "c". Pour des raisons phonétiques je comprends bien la présence de ce "ç", cependant je n'arrive pas à trouver d'autres exemples en français où un "c" se transforme en "ç". Est-ce un cas unique ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Une [liste](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/ressourcer.php) de verbes qui se conjuguent de la même façon, que j'ai complétée à l'aide d'une petite requête à mon dictionnaire (liste des mots qui admettent à la fois la terminaison *-çant* et *-cer*) :

> acquiescer, agacer, agencer, amorcer, amordancer, annoncer, autofinancer, avancer, balancer, bercer, cadencer, carencer, coincer, commencer, commercer, concurrencer, contrebalancer, courroucer, devancer, distancer, divorcer, décoincer, décontenancer, dédicacer, défoncer, déforcer, défroncer, déglacer, délacer, dénoncer, dépecer, déplacer, désagencer, désamorcer, désenlacer, effacer, efforcer, enfoncer, englacer, engoncer, enjoncer, enlacer, ensemencer, entrelacer, espacer, exaucer, exercer, fiancer, financer, foncer, forcer, forlancer, froncer, garancer, gercer, glacer, grimacer, grincer, immiscer, indicer, influencer, joncer, lacer, lancer, manigancer, matricer, menacer, mordancer, nuancer, opiacer, ordonnancer, percer, pincer, pioncer, placer, policer, poncer, prononcer, préfacer, quittancer, rapiécer, recommencer, relancer, remplacer, renfoncer, renforcer, renoncer, repercer, repincer, replacer, ressourcer, retercer, retracer, rincer, romancer, réamorcer, réensemencer, référencer, réordonnancer, saucer, semoncer, sucer, surfacer, surglacer, sérancer, tancer, tercer, tiercer, tracer, transpercer, verglacer, violacer, écorcer, élancer, émincer, énoncer, épicer, épincer, épucer, évincer

Ce n'est donc pas un cas unique. C'est la conjugaison habituelle pour les verbes du premier groupe qui terminent par *-cer*.

Answer (score 2):

Il suffit que le verbe se termine par *-cer* : 
Exemples extraits du *[site](http://www.professeurphifix.net/conj/conj_verbes_GER_CER.pdf)*

- lancer
- effacer
- prononcer
- commencer
- annoncer
- avancer
- relancer
- menacer
- placer
- percer
- agacer
- rincer
- pincer
- remplacer
- lacer